# Log SQL for NamedNativeQuery

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have defined a native sql query as NamedNativeQuery that I am triggering in my spring boot app via spring-data-jpa. Now while executing the query hibernate throws an error about syntax being incorrect. It is a pretty complex query and I would like to see in the logs, what hibernate is generating to execute. I got logging for JPQL queries working by setting the log level like below

```
org.hibernate.SQL: DEBUG
org.hibernate.type: ALL
org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql: TRACE
```

However, these does not work for the native queries (also tried show_sql=true which I don't prefer anyways at it ignores the application's logging framework and uses sysout). All it prints is the name of the query that I have used to annotate the actual query.

Any ideas/thoughts on how to log the actual SQL being used by hibernate?

**UPDATE**
Turns out since, I was using NamedNativeQuery it was just printing the name I was using and not the SQL. However, if I use the value attribute of Query annotation to define the SQL itself, it does print the raw SQL and does show all the parameter bindings based on the logging config I had shared initially.  Any ideas/thoughts on how raw sql for a NamedNativeQuery can be printed?

Answer (score 0):

There are libraries that allows to log SQL queries on jdbc driver. You can look at [p6spy](https://p6spy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration.html) or [datasource-proxy](http://ttddyy.github.io/datasource-proxy/docs/current/user-guide).